# need a row even for missing values on mysql query

Tags: mysql

Maybe my google fu is off.

I have a table: sub_transfer_jobs

```
job_date        mo_id     sub_quantity   shift_id
2017-05-16      24581     12             1
2017-05-16      86122     8              2
etc.
```

Another table: mo_numbers

```
mo_id     customer
24581     cust1
86122     cust2
68515     cust1
etc.
```

I have another table: Calendar.

```
This just has a date value for every date
```

What i need to get is a string list of amounts per day per customer

example

```
2017-05-15   cust1   50
2017-05-15   cust2   0
2017-05-16   cust1   22
2017-05-16   cust2   10
etc
```

I was going to get a distinct list of customers based one what customers are seen based on a date range

This is where i am but have a problem on the sub query

```
SELECT `sub_transfer_jobs`.`sub_quantity`, `sub_transfer_jobs`.`job_date`, `sub_transfer_jobs`.`shift_id`, `mo_numbers`.`customer`
FROM `sub_transfer_jobs`
join mo_numbers on `mo_numbers`.`mo_id` = `sub_transfer_jobs`.`mo_id`
right join calendar on `calendar`.`datefield` = `sub_transfer_jobs`.`job_date`
right join (
    select DISTINCT `mo_numbers`.`customer` from sub_transfer_jobs
    join `mo_numbers` on `mo_numbers`.`mo_id` = `sub_transfer_jobs`.`mo_id`
    where job_date > '2017-04-15'
) as customerList on customerList.customer = mo_numbers.customer
where job_date > '2017-04-15'
group by `mo_numbers`.`customer`, `sub_transfer_jobs`.`job_date`
```

EDIT: Correct sql to get what I needed (grouped for comma seperated)

```
    select basecustomer, GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(customerdaytotals.total, 0) ORDER BY datefield ASC) AS total FROM
(select basecustomer, datefield from 
 (select distinct `mo_numbers`.`customer` as basecustomer
  FROM `sub_transfer_jobs`
  JOIN `mo_numbers` on `mo_numbers`.`mo_id` = `sub_transfer_jobs`.`mo_id`
  where `sub_transfer_jobs`.`job_date` > '2017-04-01') as used_customers
 CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT `calendar`.`datefield` from `calendar`
     WHERE `calendar`.`datefield` > '2017-04-01' AND `calendar`.`datefield` < '2017-05-11'
 ) as daterange) as basedata
     LEFT JOIN (
         select `sub_transfer_jobs`.`job_date`, `mo_numbers`.`customer`, sum(`sub_transfer_jobs`.`sub_quantity`) as total
         FROM `sub_transfer_jobs`
         JOIN `mo_numbers` on `mo_numbers`.`mo_id` = `sub_transfer_jobs`.`mo_id`
         GROUP BY `sub_transfer_jobs`.`job_date`, `mo_numbers`.`customer`
     ) as customerdaytotals on customerdaytotals.job_date = basedata.datefield and customerdaytotals.customer = basedata.basecustomer
GROUP BY basecustomer
```

Which gives my result of

```
cust1   0,1857,1262,1166,517,1551,0,0,1469,1670,400,0,0,0,...
cust2   0,123,7,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,84,70,9,53,3,0,0,4...
cust3   0,0,75,425,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...
cust4   0,0,41,36,44,26,0,0,0,41,0,0,0,0,0,16,88,12,0,0,0,...
cust5   0,277,552,433,280,491,0,0,124,880,1269,0,0,0,0,495...
cust6   0,255,124,620,184,129,0,0,309,103,88,0,0,0,0,118,2...
cust7   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...
cust8   0,209,123,15,84,296,0,0,296,15,262,0,0,0,0,301,200,...
```

Comment: I don't understand how the result set relates to the data set

Comment: trying to get a summed quantity per day per customer.  if the customer has not records for that day i need 0.  I didnt put in the COALESCE on the quantity yet.  i was doing this to see if i can atleast see all the records

Comment: Which tables are the ones you showed in the question? It's hard to understand how they relate to the query you showed.

Comment: updated to reflect table names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `CROSS JOIN` to get all combinations of customers and dates. Then `LEFT JOIN` that with a query that gets each customer's total for each date.

```
SELECT m.date, c.customer, IFNULL(t.total, 0) AS total
FROM mo_numbers AS m
CROSS JOIN customer AS c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT date, mo_id, SUM(quantity) AS total
    FROM mo_numbers
    GROUP BY date, mo_id
) AS t ON m.mo_id = t.mo_id AND c.mo_id = t.mo_id
```

Comment: wasnt correct sql for what i needed but the cross join is what i needed.  Thank you.